# Debian 8 - problem with no echo in programs

Tags: debian, echo

I have a problem, because some programs and functions are not working like in Debian 7.

For example:

- reboot are not sending broadcast message,
- service [something] [start|stop] not echoing anything,

and I don't know, why it is like this...

Answer (score 1):

Debian 8 uses by default `systemd` as its init system whereas previous versions used `sysVinit`. Accordingly you need to use different ways of restarting services.

Use `systemctl [start|stop|whatever] something`, not `service`.

Reboot should still send a message. Try `shutdown -r` instead (the `reboot` command is a legacy compatibility command with systemd and may go away in the future).

Comment: Reboot are not sending a message. `shutdown -r` works ok, but `shutdown -r now` are not sending a message too...

`systemctl nginx restart` is not working: __Unknown operation 'ngingx'__.

Comment: Sorry, restart should come before the service name, not after. I've edited my answer to reflect that.